# Recharge Spring Security after permissions change

Tags: spring-security, jsp-tags

I´m using spring security to hide or show some buttons for users who has not the permissions,
but If the admin change my permisions I need that when I click the button send me a message
"Your permissions change" and hide the button, but when I try to refresh the jsp the button still there. This is because the permissions loads in the login. How can i dissapear the button?

Comment: You will probably need to write your own security filter for refreshing the authentication object.

Comment: I have a securityContext.xml, my filer must be there?  <beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor"> 
  <beans:property name="alwaysReauthenticate" value="true" /> </beans:bean> like this

Comment: Interesting... didn't know there is such configuration. That might work.